# NSObject changing property value between ViewDidLoad and cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm passing an NSManagedObject to a view controller by ways of prepareForSegue.

The object I'm assigning to is declared in the receiving viewcontroller as such:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) Allowance *allowanceSchedule;
```

Said object has a property called type which is an NSNumber.
When I pass the object to the receiving viewcontroller, this property is set to 1 in the sending viewcontroller.

In in the receiving controller, in ViewDidLoad, I can confirm this property is indeed set to 1, but in cellForRowAtIndexPath the property is set to 0 (its coredata default).
At no other point in the code I set this property. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the cellForRowAtIndexPath code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.section == 0) { // Allowance type

    if (indexPath.row == [self.allowanceSchedule.type integerValue])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}

if (indexPath.section == 1) { // Week starts on
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [Time weekStartDescriptionFromIndex:[self.allowanceSchedule.weekStart integerValue]];
}

return cell;
```

}

And here's prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqual: @"allowance"]) {
    AllowanceSetupTableViewController *allowanceViewController = (AllowanceSetupTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    allowanceViewController.delegate = self;

    if (self.child.allowanceSchedule == nil) {
        self.child.allowanceSchedule = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Allowance" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
    allowanceViewController.allowanceSchedule = self.child.allowanceSchedule;
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your code - `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as a minimum

Comment: I've edited with code. Thanks.

Comment: Odds are very good that the value is zero because the container supposedly holding it is nil.

Comment: Where is the value set to 1?

Comment: Yes, you are allocating a new core data object and passing it to your view controller. I would expect it to be 0 as you haven't initialised any other data into it

Comment: The value is set to 1 in the sending controller. But in viewDidLoad of the receiving controller, it's still set to 1. Only in cellForRow it's set to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your object is getting faulted somewhere or you're manageObjectContext is getting invalidated.  CoreData will spit out debug messages to your console, double check it and see if you have anything being printed.

Check to see if you're using the object on a different thread, or accidentally did a rollback.